# Lists with multiplication and addition Python

Tags: list, multiplication, addition

So  I have a list that has numbers like `[1,2,3,4,5]`. What I need the code to be able to multiply and add the numbers so it would look like `1*5 + 2*4 + 3*3 + 4*2 + 5*1`. Although these numbers can change based on user input, so it can also look like `[1,2,3,4]` (`1*4+2*3+3*2+4*1`)

Also, I'm only allowed to use the operations of the length of list, list accessor, create an empty list, List append.

Comment: What have you coded so far? Post an example Of what you have done and people can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result to be stored in a variable, you could do this:

```
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
s=len(y)
x=0 #initialize result to 0
for i in range(s):
    x = x + (y[i]*y[s-1-i]) 
    #y[s-1-i] is the the element to be multiplied with y[i]
print(x)
```

Comment: This solution really just uses basic operation and does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
total_sum=sum([a*b for a,b in  zip(x,x[::-1])])
```

Note: x[::-1] reverses the list